# How can I bind a model property to another property of the same instance of that model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

**TL;DR :**

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Foo:Bar>
        <Foo:Bar.Baz Blat={Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Bing, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

results in the following error message :

> - System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 :
>
>   - BindingExpression path error: 'Bing' property not found on 'object' 'RelativeSource' (HashCode=38995967)'.
>   - BindingExpression:Path=Bing; DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=38995967);
>   - target element is 'Bar' (HashCode=53937671);
>   - target property is 'Baz' (type 'Baz')`

and ends up with the binding failing - Why?

### **The Meat Of The Problem**

I have a rather convoluted `ColorModel` class which in which I have inherited `DependencyObject` as well as `INotifyPropertyChanged` :

```
[Serializable]
public class ColorModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {

}
```

Within this class are 4 double values - `Alpha`, `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` :

```
//The latter 3 DependencyProperties pretty much are the same as this : 
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    AlphaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Alpha", typeof(double),   
        typeof(ColorModel), new PropertyMetadata(1.0D));

public double Alpha {
    get { return ( double )this.GetValue( AlphaProperty ); }
    set {
        this.SetValue( AlphaProperty, value );
        this.T = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Alpha" ),
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" )
        } );
    }
}
```

Then there is the OnPropertyChanged method :

```
protected async Task OnPropertyChanged( string v ) {
    if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
        await this.PropertyChanged.Async(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( v ) ).DontBlock( );
}
```

And finally I have the `Color` property :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Color", typeof(Color), 
        typeof(ColorModel), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black));

/// <summary>
/// Get or Set Color Property.
/// </summary>
public Color Color {
    get { return ( Color )this.GetValue( ColorProperty ); }
    set {
        this.SetValue( ColorProperty, value );
        this.T = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Alpha").DontBlock( ),
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Red").DontBlock( ),
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Green").DontBlock( ),
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Blue").DontBlock( ),
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Color").DontBlock( )
        } ).DontBlock( );
    }
}
```

Never-minding the asynchronous shenanigans which are not relevant to this question, I have constructed a control which is supposed to allow a user to control all aspects of a single color :

[image]

I have each of the slide bars bound bidirectionally to the A/R/G/B properties of my ColorModel :

```
<Slider
    Value="{Binding Alpha, Mode=TwoWay}" .../>
```

And finally, Within this controls XAML I have defined the DataContext :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Controls:ColorModel>
        <Controls:ColorModel.Color>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CMC}">
                <Binding Path="Alpha" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="Red" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="Green" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="Blue" Mode="TwoWay" Source="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Controls:ColorModel.Color>
    </Controls:ColorModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

This is the converter that I am using :

```
/// <summary>
/// Class For Converting Colors To/From Raw Values.
/// </summary>
public class ColorMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert incoming raw color values into a single color.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="values">
    /// [0] : Alpha
    /// [1] : Red
    /// [2] : Green
    /// [3] : Blue
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="targetType">Color</param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Convert(
        object[ ] values,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture ) {
        return values.Contains( DependencyProperty.UnsetValue )
                ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
                : Color.FromScRgb(
                    DoubleToFloat( ( double )values[ 0 ] ),
                    DoubleToFloat( ( double )values[ 1 ] ),
                    DoubleToFloat( ( double )values[ 2 ] ),
                    DoubleToFloat( ( double )values[ 3 ] ) );
    }

    public object[ ] ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type[ ] targetTypes,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture ) {
        if ( value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue )
            return new object[ ] {
                DependencyProperty.UnsetValue,
                DependencyProperty.UnsetValue,
                DependencyProperty.UnsetValue,
                DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
            };
        Color C = ( Color )value;
        return new object[ ] {
            FloatToDouble( C.ScA ),
            FloatToDouble( C.ScR ),
            FloatToDouble( C.ScG ),
            FloatToDouble( C.ScB )
        };
    }

    private float DoubleToFloat( double d ) { return System.Convert.ToSingle( d ); }
    private double FloatToDouble( float f ) { return System.Convert.ToDouble( f ); }
}
```

And much to my chagrin and utter lack of surprise, it fails miserably. I receive the following error message(s) when I load a window with the control :

> - System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 :
>
>   - BindingExpression path error: 'Alpha' property not found on 'object'  ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=38995967)'. BindingExpression:Path=Alpha;
>   - DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=38995967);
>   - target element is 'ColorModel' (HashCode=53937671);
>   - target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')`

Which, after the longest ever of lead-ins, brings us to my question - How can I bind ( or Multi-Bind, or... whatever ) a property of a model to another property of the same instance of that model?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to find a way to do this but, at least with respects to my limited understanding, the only way I was able to do it was in the constructor of the ColorModel.

In addition, I also added a drop of code to the DependencyProperties of the model.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Color",
        typeof( Color ),
        typeof( ColorModel ),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            Colors.Black,
            async ( S, E ) =>
                await ( S as ColorModel ).OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ).DontBlock( ) ) ),
    AlphaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Alpha",
        typeof( double ),
        typeof( ColorModel ),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            1.0D,
            async ( S, E ) =>
                await ( S as ColorModel ).OnPropertyChanged( "Alpha" ).DontBlock( ) ) );
```

These DependencyProperties trigger a call to the underlying ColorModels `OnPropertyChanged` method so that anything bound through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface will be informed as well ( Untested, probably dangerous, and could likely lead to catastrophic failure via a flaming death-spiral of infinite flaming loops ).

And then in the Constructor I added the following code :

```
public ColorModel( ) {
    MultiBinding MB = new MultiBinding( );
    MB.Converter = new ColorMultiConverter( );

    MB.Bindings.Add( new Binding( "Alpha" ) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay } );
    MB.Bindings.Add( new Binding( "Red" ) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay } );
    MB.Bindings.Add( new Binding( "Green" ) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay } );
    MB.Bindings.Add( new Binding( "Blue" ) { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay } );

    BindingOperations.SetBinding( this, ColorProperty, MB );
}
```

This is the best solution I could come up with - According to the other answer, trying to use `RelativeSource` only works with `VisualTree` elements so I guess that explains why it failed when I tried to do it in XAML.

Answer (score -1):

`RelativeSource` will work only with `VisualTree` elements. It won't work for normal class/property scenarios. So, in your case `RelativeSource` would be hitting the control where `DataContext` is applied.

[CoerceValueCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.100).aspx) and [PropertyChangedCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback(v=vs.100).aspx) are used to enforce relationships between properties.

Example,

`Slider` control uses value coercion for its `SelectionStart` and `SelectionEnd` properties.

```
Slider.SelectionStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionStart", typeof(double), typeof(Slider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(Slider.OnSelectionStartChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(Slider.CoerceSelectionStart)), new ValidateValueCallback(Slider.IsValidDoubleValue));

private static object CoerceSelectionStart(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    Slider slider = (Slider)d;
    double num = (double)value;
    double minimum = slider.Minimum;
    double maximum = slider.Maximum;
    if (num < minimum)
    {
        return minimum;
    }
    if (num > maximum)
    {
        return maximum;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Same way, you too can achieve multiple property dependency in your VM.

Few links :

[Dr. Wpf](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/05/05/value-coercion-for-the-masses/)

Comment: What do the sliders have to do with the `ColorModel`? I could implement this model into any control, regardless of the presence ( or absence ) of sliders and attempt to bind the `ColorModel`s properties to its own other properties, and I'd bet I would still see this error come up.

Comment: @Will When you will use `CoerceValueCallbak`, then no need for your `Binding` at all.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me why RelativeSource did not work.